# File upload and move problem with express-fileupload

Tags: node.js, express

**I have this file/folder structure:**

```
+--public
|    +--/productsImg/   //folder where i want to move images
+--routes
|    +--products.js    //the part that tells the images to move to /public/productImg/
```

**In order to move a specific image i have used *EXPRESS-FILEUPLOAD module***.

I want all the images to be in /public/productsImg/ folder. SEE the above for the folder/file structure.

In *products.js* i wrote the following code:

```
var image = req.files; // in VIEW <input type="file" name="image"/>

var uploadPath = path.resolve(__dirname, '../public/productsImg/' + image.name);

//console.log(uploadPath) gives nothing ;

image.mv(uploadPath, (err) => {

  if (err) {
    return res.status(500).send(err);
  }

  res.send('File uploaded to ' + uploadPath);

});
```

I have this error in nodemon console : `POST /products/store 500 9.733 ms - 16104`

I think may be i'm not using correctly the `path.resolve` part and my uploadPath variable (file) is unknow, i think.

Have seen other posts, i couldn't figure it out. Any ideas?

Comment: try to use `path.join(__dirname, '../public/productsImg/' + image.name)`

Comment: tried it. It doesn't work!

Comment: whats the log output of `__dirname` ??

Comment: @NasiruddinSaiyed nothing... ! i m confused...

Comment: did you declared `app.use(fileUpload());` in your express server ?? it need to be called as per example https://github.com/richardgirges/express-fileupload/tree/master/example

Comment: @NasiruddinSaiyed yes i have app.use(fileUpload());!

Answer (score 1):

May be it can help someone: solution

**1)** Added `var path = required('path');` in product.js eventhough i added this in my app.js. It is important otherwise it won't work.

**2)** Created /tmp/ folder (root of your project) and add this in app

```
app.use(fileUpload({
  useTempFiles : true,
  tempFileDir : '/tmp/'
}));
```

**3)** Changed the code to

```
var { image } = req.files;

var uploadPath = path.resolve(__dirname, '../public/productsImg/', image.name); // important

console.log(uploadPath);

image.mv(uploadPath, (err) => {

  if (err) {
    return res.status(500).send(err);
  }

  res.send('File uploaded to ' + uploadPath);
  //or whatever you want to do

});
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your example, your file object should be in req.files.image.
See express-fileupload documetnation:

Example:

- You're uploading a file called car.jpg
- Your input's name field is foo:
- In your express server request, you can access your uploaded file from req.files.foo:

```
app.post('/upload', function(req, res) {
  console.log(req.files.foo); // the uploaded file object
});
```

Answer (score -1):

hie, in express-fileupload you access the image via the name attribute, so you might consider changing

`var image = req.files`

to

`var image = req.files.image`

hope it helps

Comment: req.files is an object with different key value. if i write  var image = req.files.image the image.mv will not be availaible!!! Anyways i have tried your code it doesn't work. ty for sharing.